# How to exclude particular directory and all files under that directory in tcl

Tags: tcl, glob

I am beginner in tcl.

I am able to write script for collecting all files under a directory and it's all subdirectory.

I have written a belwo proc for the same.

```
proc rglob { dirpath } {
    set rlist ""
    foreach fpath [glob -nocomplain -types f -directory ${dirpath} *] {
            lappend rlist ${fpath}
    }
    foreach dir [glob -nocomplain -types d -directory ${dirpath} *] {
            lappend rlist {*}[rglob ${dir}]
    }
    return ${rlist}
}



rglob /a/b/c
```

will give you all files withing dir c and its subdirectories.

Now consider a case I want to exclude few directories under c say dir1 and dir2 are the two directory and I want to exclude a directory dir2. Please guide me how should I proceed for the same. 
`set exclude_dir dir2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exclude from search resuls all directories with names in exclude_dirs_list. In fact, names are not full paths, so not only /a/b/c/dir1 will be excluded, but /a/b/c/d/e/dir1 too.

```
proc rglob { dirpath exclude_dirs_list} {
    set rlist ""
    foreach fpath [glob -nocomplain -tails -types f -directory ${dirpath} *] {
            lappend rlist [file join ${dirpath} ${fpath}]
    }
    foreach dir [glob -nocomplain -tails -types d -directory ${dirpath} *] {
      if {[lsearch -exact $exclude_dirs_list $dir] == -1} {
        lappend rlist {*}[rglob [file join ${dirpath} ${dir}] $exclude_dirs_list]
      }
    }
    return ${rlist}
}

rglob /a/b/c [list dir1 dir2]
```

If you need to exclude only /a/b/c/dir1 you should change from

```
lappend rlist {*}[rglob [file join ${dirpath} ${dir}] $exclude_dirs_list]
```

to

```
lappend rlist {*}[rglob [file join ${dirpath} ${dir}] {}]
```

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use `if {$dir ni $exclud_dirs_list} {` for the directory inclusion test (`ni` for Not In), but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

This code is basically the same as in the accepted answer, but a little simpler:

```
proc rglob {dirpath args} {
    set exclude $args
    set rlist [glob -nocomplain -types f -directory $dirpath *]
    foreach dir [glob -nocomplain -types d -directory $dirpath *] {
        if {$dir ni $exclude} {
            lappend rlist {*}[rglob $dir {*}$exclude]
        }
    }
    return $rlist
}
```

**Usage:** `rglob dirpath ?arg arg ...?`, e.g. `rglob .`, `rglob . ./abc ./def`.

The matching of directory names could be improved by using glob or regexp matching.

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[ni (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)